# How to test HTTParty API call with Ruby and RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, httparty

I am using the HTTParty gem to make a call to the GitHub API to access a list of user's repos.

It is a very simple application using Sinatra that displays a user's favourite programming language based on the most common language that appears in their repos.

I am a bit stuck on how I can write an RSpec expectation that mocks out the actual API call and instead just checks that json data is being returned.

I have a mock .json file but not sure how to use it in my test.

Any ideas?

**github_api.rb**

```
require 'httparty'

class GithubApi
  attr_reader :username, :data, :languages

  def initialize(username)
    @username = username
    @response = HTTParty.get("https://api.github.com/users/#{@username}/repos")
    @data = JSON.parse(@response.body)
  end
end
```

**github_api_spec.rb**

```
require './app/models/github_api'
require 'spec_helper'

describe GithubApi do
  let(:github_api) { GithubApi.new('mock_user') }

  it "receives a json response" do

  end
end
```

*Rest of the files for clarity:*

**results.rb**

```
require 'httparty'
require_relative 'github_api'

class Results

 def initialize(github_api = Github.new(username))
   @github_api = github_api
   @languages = []
 end

 def get_languages
   @github_api.data.each do |repo|
     @languages << repo["language"]
   end
 end

 def favourite_language
   get_languages
   @languages.group_by(&:itself).values.max_by(&:size).first
 end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
require './config/environment'
require 'sinatra/base'
require './app/models/github_api'

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

  configure do
    enable :sessions
    set :session_secret, "@3x!ilt£"
    set :views, 'app/views'
  end

  get "/" do
    erb :index
  end

  post "/user" do
    @github = GithubApi.new(params[:username])
    @results = Results.new(@github)
    @language = @results.favourite_language
    session[:language] = @language
    session[:username] = params[:username]
    redirect '/results'
  end

  get "/results" do
    @language = session[:language]
    @username = session[:username]
    erb :results
  end

run! if app_file == $0

end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could approach this problem.

You could, as @anil suggested, use a library like webmock to mock the underlying HTTP call. You could also do something similar with VCR (https://github.com/vcr/vcr) which records the results of an actual call to the HTTP endpoint and plays back that response on subsequent requests.

But, given your question, I don't see why you couldn't just use an Rspec double. I'll show you how below. But, first, it would be a bit easier to test the code if it were not all in the constructor.

**github_api.rb**

```
require 'httparty'

class GithubApi
  attr_reader :username

  def initialize(username)
    @username = username
  end

  def favorite_language
    # method to calculate which language is used most by username
  end

  def languages
    # method to grab languages from repos
  end

  def repos
    repos ||= do
      response = HTTParty.get("https://api.github.com/users/#{username}/repos")
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you do not need to reference the `@username` variable in the url because you have an `attr_reader`.

**github_api_spec.rb**

```
require './app/models/github_api'
require 'spec_helper'

describe GithubApi do
  subject(:api) { described_class.new(username) }

  let(:username) { 'username' }

  describe '#repos' do
    let(:github_url) { "https://api.github.com/users/#{username}/repos" }
    let(:github_response) { instance_double(HTTParty::Response, body: github_response_body) }
    let(:github_response_body) { 'response_body' }

    before do
      allow(HTTParty).to receive(:get).and_return(github_response)
      allow(JSON).to receive(:parse)

      api.repos
    end

    it 'fetches the repos from Github api' do
      expect(HTTParty).to have_received(:get).with(github_url)
    end

    it 'parses the Github response' do
      expect(JSON).to have_received(:parse).with(github_response_body)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that there is no need to actually load or parse any real JSON. What we're testing here is that we made the correct HTTP call and that we called `JSON.parse` on the response. Once you start testing the `languages` method you'd need to actually load and parse your test file, like this:

```
let(:parsed_response) { JSON.parse(File.read('path/to/test/file.json')) }
```

Comment: thanks so much for your helpful solution! Exactly what I was after in terms of understanding how and what to test, much appreciated :)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can mock those API calls using https://github.com/bblimke/webmock and send back mock.json using webmock. This post, https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests walks you through the setup of webmock with RSpec (the tests in the post mock GitHub API call too)